# Symfony 3 EntityManager in PRE_SET_DATA

Tags: symfony

After lots of hours searching I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I'm working with Symfony 3.1.6.

Here's my question:

I have an entity Customer with the attribute country (integer) based in the id of the entity Country. I don't want to create a relationship between this two entities because I don't want to add an attribute in the Country entity each time another entity need it (Users, Customers, Leads, ...).

I have a LocationType form which I embedded in the CustomerType.

The CountryType form field is based on the code2A of the countries, then I have this as an attribute in the Country entity.

In the FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA I want to use the Customer country, an integer, to search it's correspondant code2a to set the right CountryType option selected when presenting the combobox.

Here's the code of the LocationType:

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CountryType;

class LocationType extends AbstractType
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }


    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $country_field = array(
            'required' => false,
            'placeholder' => 'Choose country',
            'empty_data' => null,
            'mapped' => true,
            'attr' => array('v-model' => 'selected_country')
        );

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($country_field) {
                $form = $event->getForm();
                $data = $event->getForm()->getParent()->getData();

                $filtered_country_field = $country_field;

                if (!empty($data->getCountry())) {
                    echo '<pre>('.$data->getCountry().')</pre><br />';

                    $repo = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Country');
                    $country = $repo->find($data->getCountry());

                    echo '<pre>Country code 2a ('.$country->getCode2a().')</pre><br />';

                    //$filtered_country_field['attr']['data-selected'] = $data->getCountry()->getCode2a();
                }else{
                    echo 'No country.<br />';
                }
                //echo '<pre>'; print_r ($filtered_country_field); echo '</pre>';
                //exit;

                $form->add('country', CountryType::class, $filtered_country_field);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

But when executing I have this error:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Form\LocationType::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormRegistry.php on line 85
```

But everywhere I look uses the same way to get the em...

Any help will be usefull.

Comment: Define your form type as a service: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service in order to get the entity manager injected.  By the way, a many to one unidirectional relation will require no changes to your country entity. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional

Comment: Thanks Cerad, I wil try this path..